# Is it true that some early modern Europeans refused to believe giraffes existed?

Tags: europe, animals

I remember reading or hearing somewhere that some of the first Europeans to see a giraffe in Europe refused to believe that such a creature could really exist. Presumably they thought the giraffe(s) they'd seen were some kind of illusion or an elaborate mechanical prank. I believe (but am not certain) the story related either to the Medici Giraffe (in Florence, Italy in the 1400s), or to the giraffe now known as Zarafa* that lived in Paris in the early-mid 1800s. It's also possible it relates to one of the other giraffes in Europe around the same time as Zarafa - I think these were in London and Vienna, but they didn't survive long.

There's quite a bit of information on these giraffes and the reaction to them online. E.g. see the [Medici Giraffe](https://www.welt.de/geschichte/article124995638/So-kurz-war-das-Giraffen-Leben-am-Medici-Hof.html) (in German, but hopefully Google translate will give you the gist if you don't speak it), or  '[Zarafa](https://www.google.com/amp/s/amp.theguardian.com/science/animal-magic/2014/jan/20/zarafa-giraffe-paris-fashion)'

There's a little bit of information on the public reaction to the giraffes in those and other articles I've read, but nothing that relates to the anecdote I heard. There are a couple of books on them but they're not available in my local library system and to be honest I don't really want to buy a book (or several) just to answer this quirky question. So I'm wondering if anyone can confirm:

1. is it true that some people (or at least someone) refused to believe in giraffes even after seeing them?
2. if so, where is this reaction documented?
3. Was this a common reaction or just one or two people?

* I believe the name Zarafa was given long after the giraffe died but using it as it seems to be the widely known name.
** By the way, I realise the calling the mid 1800s 'early modern' in my question is debatable but wanted to give some indication of the general time period without making the question too long.

Comment: I see nothing surprising here.  You see something physically implausible which has not been seen live ever or at least recently in your location, but which has been modelled artificially. So some people might think what they were seeing was more likely to be a new better model than an actual animal.

Comment: Thanks Henry. I agree it wouldn't be particularly surprising if true. Just trying to find out if any response like this is confirmed/documented.

Comment: The "first giraffes in Europe" likely were seen in ancient Rome at some sort of games.

Comment: You're quite right there andejons. Sorry, I should have been more precise with my language at the start. Here's an article on giraffes in ancient Rome that also mentions the later ones. https://penelope.uchicago.edu/~grout/encyclopaedia_romana/gladiators/giraffe.html  Doesn't answer my question though, unfortunately.